# Pass shared_ptr as argument with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a function implemented in func.hpp by C++ as

```
void func(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<double> > &x) {
    //something is doing here.
}
```

and in the swig .i file, I have added

```
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%shared_ptr(DoubleValue)
%template(doublevec) std::vector<double>;
%template(doubleptrvec) std::vector<std::shared_ptr<double> >;
%{
#include "func.hpp"
}
%include "func.hpp"
```

When I call the function in python as

```
x=0.1
func([x])
```

I got error saying TypeError: in method 'func', argument 2 of type 'std::vector< std::shared_ptr< double >,std::allocator< std::shared_ptr< double > > >'.

I think I must do something to pass python objects as pointers to C++ function: does anyone have experience for this?

Comment: The type of `%shared_ptr(DoubleValue)` doesn't exist, and you can't use a primitive type (`double`) with `%shared_ptr()`.  Why do you need a `vector<shared_ptr<double>>` and not just a `vector<vector<double>>`?

Comment: it complies successfully with %shared_ptr(DoubleValue), should I use others? The idea of using vector<shared_ptr<double>>  is to track and log some variables.